# Print calculated Value of variable before its been calculated

Tags: php, mysqli

This is a tricky question to search, hence my post here. I have a a header that displays the sum of all the values in a column of a table that is printed below it. However the table is generated from a MYSQL table and the sum of the column values is calculated as it is generated. So somehow I have to have a variable printed but only after the table is generated and I am not sure how to pass the variables back up to the print statement so it doesn't always print out a 0

I feel like the solution is that the sum should call a script (Javascipt) that generates and prints the table returning the sum of columns to then be printed. But I am not sure how I would do this

```
echo "
    <h3>EPL</h3>
    <h5>Total Score: $total</h5>
    <table class='table table-bordered'>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Score</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody class='row_position'>"?>
        <?php

        require('db_config.php');
        $tablename = $_SESSION['username'] . "_epl";
        $_SESSION['tablename'] = $tablename;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tablename ORDER BY position_order";
        $users = $mysqli->query($sql);
        while($user = $users->fetch_assoc()){
        $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'predictions');
        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `predictions`.`".$tablename."` WHERE (CONVERT(`title` USING utf8) LIKE '%".$user['title']."%')";
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `predictions`.`epl` WHERE (CONVERT(`title` USING utf8) LIKE '%".$user['title']."%')";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $position1 = $row['position_order'];
        $result->close();
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $position2 = $row['position_order'];
        $total += abs($position1-$position2);



        ?>
            <tr  id="<?php echo $user['id'] ?>">
                <td><?php echo $user['position_order'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $user['title'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo abs($position1-$position2); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

To explain the table further, each user has their own table with the same format username_league, so I use some php code to grab the table. Additionally I have a base case table in this case 'epl' in which I compare the tables and calculate the scores based on the absolute difference in the column 'position_order'.

Comment: Just run your database code at the top of the file...

Comment: And do you really have a separate database table for each user in your system? That's fairly scary. I know storage and cycles are cheap these days, but that's a *huge* amount of overhead. You need to read up on [database design](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/relational_database_design.html) and rethink your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always aim for separation of your code and presentation. And beyond that, your database code is extremely inefficient. You're re-creating an entire database object for every instance of your original query.

Just put your PHP code before the HTML, or better yet in a separate file.

```
<?php

$total = 0;

require('db_config.php');
$tablename = $_SESSION['username'] . "_epl";
$_SESSION['tablename'] = $tablename;
$sql = "SELECT id, position_order, title FROM `$tablename` ORDER BY position_order";
$users_result = $mysqli->query($sql);
while($user = $users_result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $users[] = $user;
}

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $sql1 = "
        SELECT position_order FROM `$tablename` WHERE CONVERT(`title` USING utf8) LIKE '%$user[title]%' LIMIT 1
        UNION
        SELECT position_order FROM `epl` WHERE CONVERT(`title` USING utf8) LIKE '%$user[title]%' LIMIT 1
    ";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql1);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $position1 = $row['position_order'];
    $user["position1"] = $position1;

    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $position2 = $row['position_order'];
    $user["position2"] = $position2;

    $total += abs($position1 - $position2);
}
?>
```

There you are; using a single database object, one third fewer queries, all your values in an array. They're ready to use later in the file, or in your separate HTML view:

```
<h3>EPL</h3>
<h5>Total Score: <?=$total?></h5>
<table class='table table-bordered'>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Score</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody class='row_position'>

    <?php foreach($users as $user):?>
        <tr  id="<?=$user['id'] ?>">
            <td><?=$user['position_order'] ?></td>
            <td><?=$user['title'] ?></td>
            <td><?=abs($user["position1"]-$user["position2"]); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I don't know enough about the structure here, but I'd be very surprised if you couldn't make this a single database query.

Comment: Thank you so much for this comprehensive answer, as this if my first foray with using mysql and databases, I know what I am writing/implementing is not efficient but I don't know a better way. I will read the guide you posted and keep googling around as I work

Answer (score 1):

Output buffering is your friend! Simply call [`ob_start`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) before outputting the table i.e.

```
ob_start();
echo "
<table class='table table-bordered'>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Score</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody class='row_position'>"?>
...
```

then once you have done generating the table, you can collect the output of the table's content using [`ob_get_clean`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php), output the header and then the table content:

```
...
$table = ob_get_clean();
echo "<h3>EPL</h3>
<h5>Total Score: $total</h5>";
echo $table;
```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer, Im glad to have learned this new tool!

Comment: @Marc-9 I actually made a mistake in the code - sorry. I've corrected the answer.